# PHP How to get a method name with a class and namespace path as a string?

Tags: php, string, class, methods, namespaces

I really hate to write this question because I'm kind-of "research guy" and, well, I always find what I'm searching for... But this one bugs me a lot and I can't find the answer anywhere... So, here it goes:

As the title says I need to get a method name with the trailing class and namespace path as a string. I mean something like this: `"System\Language\Text::loadLanguageCache"`.
As we know, you can get a class name (with full namespace path) by typing, i.e.: `Text::class` and it returns `"System\Language\Text"`, but is there a way to get this for a method? Something like: `Text::loadLanguageCache::function` to get string: `"System\Language\Text::loadLanguageCache"`?

Edit:

I think I should explain this further... I know about magic constant `__METHOD__` but the problem is that it works *inside the called method* and I need this *"outside the method"*.
Take this as example:

```
//in System\Helpers
function someFunction()
{ return __METHOD__; }
```

That's all OK with this if I call the function I'll get (let's assume that method is in `System\Helpers` class) - `"System\Helpers::someFunction"`. But what I want is this:

```
//in System\Helpers
function someFunction()
{ //some code... whatever }

// somewhere not in System\Helpers
function otherFunction()
{
    $thatFunctionName = Helpers::someFunction::method //That imaginary thing I want

    $thatClassName = Helpers::class; //this returns "System\Helpers"
}
```

I hope this cleared my question a bit :)

Comment: Why not simply `Text::class . '::loadLanguageCache'`? I can't think of any reason why you'd *need* anything else, even if it may be nice to have.

Comment: Well if there's no such a thing that I want, I guess I'm stuck with `Text::class . '::loadLanguageCache'`... But it would be very nice to have :)

Comment: I'm not entirely clear what you have now - in the example you cite, the line of code `$thatFunctionName = Helpers::someFunction::method;` already includes the answer you want, so you could just type `$thatFunctionName = 'someFunction';`. Presumably there is a more complex scenario you're thinking of where this wouldn't be the case, but I'm struggling to imagine it.

Comment: `$thatFunctionName = Helpers::someFunction::method;` - that was the imaginary line, because `method` thing does not exist. Of course I could just type: `$thatFunctionName = 'System\Helpers::someFunction';` but that is just not nice because of refactoring, possible namespace changes, class name changes and so on :)

Comment: I think the reason this wouldn't be useful is that methods rarely need to be represented in a fully-qualified form like that. For a callback, for instance, you'd use an array: `[Helpers::class, 'someFunction']`; and for an instance (non-static) method, a string with `::` in it would be just plain wrong. So take the qualified class name and, for your purposes, append `'::someFunction'` as a hard-coded string, since it's hard-coded even in your imaginary syntax.

Comment: I want that whole string because I send it as an AJAX parameter and I don't want two separate strings for class and method (PHP calls it to handle request using reflection). Concatenating that string is all fine, I just thought there is kind of "nicer" way :)

Comment: i'm looking for this because i use laravel and i don't want the controller actions (what methods from what classes to call) in my routes to be expressed inside strings like 'UserController@authenticate'... using a string, i don't have the benefits of code refactoring in my IDE... would like to know if you found a way around this.

Comment: Unfortunately i have not found that "nice" way just because it does not exist and probably will never be implemented in php... +1 for Laravel - such a great framework :)

Comment: Such an underrated question. It is these fine details that make you love and adore your code. It can be much more difficult to find references to a method if you hard-code strings like that, but an equivalent of ::class as ::method instead would be such a blessing for fine code. I have not found the solution online yet that we seem to look for, but I think it can also be difficult to formulate this issue--specifically--as a simple, searchable question. Any luck, 6 years later?

Comment: @HelloWorld Not really I just bountied a question which is essentially asking for the same thing and someone drove me to this question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66238766/php-callback-is-there-an-equivalent-for-class-for-a-method-of-a-class?noredirect=1). We have is_callable and call_user_func but not exactly the great thing which is requested here. Do you think it is worth a PHP feature request?

Answer (score 3):

You  must use the magic constant, you can read more about at [Magic constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) in php.net

```
__METHOD__
```

Outside of the class you must use [Reflection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.reflection.php) as is explained at [ReflectionClass](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionclass.getmethods.php) documentation:

```
<?php
$class = new ReflectionClass('ReflectionClass');
$method = $class->getMethod('getMethod');
var_dump($method);
?>;
```

Returns:

```
object(ReflectionMethod)#2 (2) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(9) "getMethod"
  ["class"]=>
  string(15) "ReflectionClass"
}
```

Comment: I know about this magic constant, but it works inside a method, and I need this to work "outside" the method...

Comment: Yeah, that's what I want, and I know about Reflection too. But the whole idea of a question was the simplicity, to just use Foo::someMethod::method to get that string (as easily as you can do with Foo::class). :)

Comment: But the class name not is obvious but the method yes, just $methodPath = Helpers::class . 'theMethod'; you cannot use AS in methods. :/